# XCode 7 - Misplaced views warning for view in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have added a UIView on storyboard in which i set a constraints to top,left,bottom,right as shown below

As you can see in the image, orange bordered line indicates that i misplaced the view.

[image]

[image]

My UIView position is 0,20,320,150. I am not sure why xcode shows the warning eventhough i set a correct constraint.

[image]

I am using Xcode 7 beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints doesn't respect you frame.
You have frame `0, 20, 320, 150`, but constraints show `Trailing Space: -20` and `Leading Space: -20`. Set both of them to `-16` and warnings will disappear.
You need set `-16` because your constraints related to margins, not to actual bounds. Margin has `16` points offset from bounds.

Comment: What does it mean?. I didn't change any constraint. When i place my view. The constraint set to -20

Comment: @iPhoneGuy probably you changed view frame by stretching it to the superview bounds. In this case constraints will not be updated automatically.

Comment: i am not sure. I just tried adding view to my container and set the leading space to superview. The constraint set to 20 instead of 16. I think there might be issue with new Xcode

Comment: Did this happen after update to Xcode 7? I get similar warnings and it appears to me that the margins have all changed from 16 to 20, hence the -4 error on constraints to the superview edge. I am changing all my constraints to accommodate this change in margin width and that seems to be clearing the warnings.