# Xcode Storyboard XML Tag Meanings

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a project that was originated before storyboards.  It's been updated to use them but every once in a while weirdness crops back up.

This latest weirdness happened when I built the project in Xcode 7 Beta, decided that it was way too much to fix everything before release, and then opened it back up in Xcode 6.

One of the views behaved VERY differently after that but the only difference I could find was when I viewed the XML.

Old:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MI7-ps-W1t" userLabel="Header">
```

New:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MI7-ps-W1t" userLabel="Header">
```

Question #1

What does the "misplaced" tag even mean in relationship to a storyboard?  I had not warnings or conflicts in the storyboard at the time.

Question #2

Why did it change when compiling with Xcode 7 beta?  I saw this post: [XCode 7 - Misplaced views warning for view in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749947/xcode-7-misplaced-views-warning-for-view-in-storyboard), but that really doesn't answer the question.

Question #3

Is there a place that I'm missing that has an explanation of the XML tags used for storyboards?  Most of them are self-explanatory but some of them are cryptic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the view's constraints and position don't agree.

Xcode 7 is likely a bit more robust in its checks, and is detecting something that Xcode 6 missed.

Just because you can mostly get away with moving back to an earlier release, it doesn't mean you should go backward, tools-wise.

One of the issues is that Xcode silently rewrites older XML to account for changes.  Whether or not you made explicit storyboard changes in Xcode 7, Xcode 7 likely silently rewrote the XML.

Any change Xcode 7 made may be tripping up Xcode 6 now.  You may want to revert your project to its pre-Xcode 7 state, either via source control or Time Machine.

As for the Storyboard XML tags, I don't think they're publicly documented anywhere.

Comment: Thanks!  Sadly what I expected but it's at least nice to have it confirmed.  Thanks for your wisdom.